# Android Studio - Not Seeing Galaxy s5 device

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, development-environment

I've seen a lot on getting your device as a target in android studio, but it seems like i've tried everything and can't seem to get it on my phone.

I have my developer options enabled, along with usb debugging, MTP selected, the driver for my phone is updated, also have Samsung Mobile USB Composite Device updated, i've unplugged and plugged it and turned all of these things on and off several times.

In Deployment Target Options I have "USB Device" selected. When I try running it still says "no target device found"

Are there any other tricks that you guys might have up your sleeve? New to Android Studio.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Did you check `Device Manager` on Windows to find any drivers got issue?

Comment: Have you try with adb command, like that, adb devices

Comment: Windows 10, i have an adb driver installed yes. I'm not certain exactly what other drivers are needed but my pc is recognizing it as a device, just not android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Samsung USB driver and that worked for me.

This is the link: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

I hope this works for you.